# How to compute the total sum of squared error in k-mean clustering matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, k-means

I am implementing the k-means algorithm for given 4-dimensional data with k=# of cluster and i am running about 5 times with different initial points.

1. How can i compute the total sum of squared error (SSE)after each run?

```css
4 Dimention 1 to 4 and blow
x1 1 2 3 4
x2 5 6 7 8
x3 9 10 11 12
x4 13 14 15 16
x5 17 18 19 20
```

I will be more than happy if anyone can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have trouble using the built in `kmeans` function, or are you building one from scratch?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Thank you for your comment. Actually i am able to use the kmeans built in function but in the example in matlab help i couldn't understand how should i calculate the mean, center, size of cluster and list of data which are assigned to each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The `kmeans()` function already gives everything that you want directly. It has the following syntax for 3 clusters:

```
[idx,CentreCoordinates,SEE] = kmeans(yourData,3);
```

where

- `idx` is the label of each observation (values 1 to 3 in this case)
- `CentreCoordinates` are the coordinates of the cluster centres (each row is one centre)
- `SEE` is the summed within-cluster euclidian distance of every observation to its nearest cluster centre -  the SEE.

Since you actually don't need the indexes, you can ignore the first output of the function with `~` (tilde):

```
[~,CentreCoordinates,SEE] = kmeans(yourData,3);
```

Comment: If you have trouble reading the .xls file, `yourData = xlsread('path/to/file/filename.xls','B:E');` should do it. Like this it only reads columns 2:5, since column 1 is useless.

Answer (score 1):

This code is with the inbuilt MATLAB function 'k-means'. You need to modify it with your own algorithm for k-means. It shows the calculation of cluster centoirds and sum of square errors (also called the distrotion).

```
clc; close all; clear all; 
data = readtable('data.txt'); % Importing the data-set
d1 = table2array(data(:, 2)); % Data in first dimension 
d2 = table2array(data(:, 3)); % Data in second dimension
d3 = table2array(data(:, 4)); % Data in third dimension 
d4 = table2array(data(:, 5)); % Data in fourth dimension 
X = [d1, d2, d3, d4]; % Combining the data into a matrix
k = 3; % Number of clusters
idx = kmeans(X, 3); % Alpplying the k-means using inbuilt funciton 
%% Separating the data in different dimension
d1_1 = d1(idx == 1); % d1 for the data in cluster 1 
d2_1 = d2(idx == 1); % d2 for the data in cluster 1
d3_1 = d3(idx == 1); % d3 for the data in cluster 1
d4_1 = d4(idx == 1); % d4 for the data in cluster 1
%==============================
d1_2 = d1(idx == 2); % d1 for the data in cluster 2 
d2_2 = d2(idx == 2); % d2 for the data in cluster 2
d3_2 = d3(idx == 2); % d3 for the data in cluster 2
d4_2 = d4(idx == 2); % d4 for the data in cluster 2
%==============================
d1_3 = d1(idx == 3); % d1 for the data in cluster 3
d2_3 = d2(idx == 3); % d2 for the data in cluster 3
d3_3 = d3(idx == 3); % d3 for the data in cluster 3
d4_3 = d4(idx == 3); % d4 for the data in cluster 3
%% Finding the co-ordinates of the cluster centroids
c1_d1 = mean(d1_1); % d1 value of the centroid for cluster 1
c1_d2 = mean(d2_1); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 1
c1_d3 = mean(d3_1); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 1
c1_d4 = mean(d4_1); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 1
%====================================
c2_d1 = mean(d1_2); % d1 value of the centroid for cluster 2
c2_d2 = mean(d2_2); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 2
c2_d3 = mean(d3_2); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 2
c2_d4 = mean(d4_2); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 2
%====================================
c3_d1 = mean(d1_3); % d1 value of the centroid for cluster 3
c3_d2 = mean(d2_3); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 3
c3_d3 = mean(d3_3); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 3
c3_d4 = mean(d4_3); % d2 value of the centroid for cluster 3
%% Calculating the distortion
distortion = 0; % Initialization
for n1 = 1 : length(d1_1)    
    distortion = distortion + ( ( ( c1_d1 - d1_1(n1) ).^2 ) + ( ( c1_d2 - d2_1(n1) ).^2 ) + ...
                                                    ( ( c1_d3 - d3_1(n1) ).^2 ) + ( ( c1_d4 - d4_1(n1) ).^2 ) );                                                 
end
for n2 = 1 : length(d1_2)    
    distortion = distortion + ( ( ( c2_d1 - d1_2(n2) ).^2 ) + ( ( c2_d2 - d2_2(n2) ).^2 ) + ...
                                                    ( ( c2_d3 - d3_2(n2) ).^2 ) + ( ( c2_d4 - d4_2(n2) ).^2 ) );                                                 
end
for n3 = 1 : length(d1_3)    
    distortion = distortion + ( ( ( c3_d1 - d1_3(n3) ).^2 ) + ( ( c3_d2 - d2_3(n3) ).^2 ) + ...
                                                    ( ( c3_d3 - d3_3(n3) ).^2 ) + ( ( c3_d4 - d4_3(n3) ).^2 ) );                                                 
end
fprintf('The unnormalized sum of square error is %f\n', distortion);
fprintf('The co-ordinate of the cluster 1 is \t d1 = %f, d2 = %f, d3 = %f, d4 = %f\n', c1_d1, c1_d2, c1_d3, c1_d4);
fprintf('The co-ordinate of the cluster 2 is \t d1 = %f, d2 = %f, d3 = %f, d4 = %f\n', c2_d1, c2_d2, c2_d3, c2_d4);
fprintf('The co-ordinate of the cluster 3 is \t d1 = %f, d2 = %f, d3 = %f, d4 = %f\n', c3_d1, c3_d2, c3_d3, c3_d4);
```

Comment: You can verify the answers by using the command '[idx,CentreCoordinates,SEE] = kmeans(X,3);'

Comment: Thanks for your comment and code. I tried to run your code in my side to see whats happening but i am getting error as : 'Variable index exceeds table dimensions'. in for line 6: 'd4 = table2array(data(:, 5)); % Data in fourth dimension' . Would you please let me know why i am getting this error. thanks

Comment: In **my version**, when I saved the data and imported using 'data = readtable('data.txt');' the first column contains the data number, the second column contains the d1 values, the third column refers to d2 values, the fourth column contains d3 values and **the fifth column contains the d4 values**. That is what happening in 'd4 = table2array(data(:, 5));'. I guess in your version you might **not** have saved the data number and that's why you're getting the error probably.

Comment: Thanks. Now i am able to run in my side.